# Longest substring with 2 unique characters in a given string at linear time

Tags: java, performance, strings

This is my java implementation based on the solution of Aasmund Eldhuset [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997262/how-to-find-the-longest-substring-containing-two-unique-repeating-characters).
Please give your opinion on my code (correctness, efficiency and coding conventions):

```
public static String longest2Str(String s){
    int len;
    int i = 1;
    int subStart = 0;
    int nextGroupStart = 0;
    int longestStart = 0;
    int longestEnd = 0;
    char firstUnique, secondUnique, c;

    if ( (s == null) || (s.length() < 2) ) {
        return null;
    }

    len = s.length();
    firstUnique = s.charAt(subStart);

    // find first letter in s that isn't equal to the firstUnique 
    for (; (i < len) && (s.charAt(i) == firstUnique); i++);

    secondUnique = s.charAt(i);
    for (; i < len; i++) {
        c = s.charAt(i);
        if ( (c == firstUnique) || (c == secondUnique) ) {
            if (c != s.charAt(i - 1)) {
                nextGroupStart = i;
            }   
        }
        else {
            if ( i - subStart > longestEnd - longestStart ){
                longestStart = subStart;
                longestEnd = i;
            }
            subStart = nextGroupStart;
            nextGroupStart = i;
            firstUnique = s.charAt(subStart);
            secondUnique = c;
        }
    }

    return s.substring(longestStart, longestEnd);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Corner cases

You correctly handle the corner cases of too short input and null input.
But you forgot to handle the case of all same characters, for example "aaa".
On such input the program throws `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` on line `secondUnique = s.charAt(i);`.

#### Variable scope

The variable `c` is only needed within the main `for` loop,
so it would be best to declare it inside the loop.

#### Style

This is fine:

> ```
> for (; (i < len) && (s.charAt(i) == firstUnique); i++);
> ```

But it looks a bit strange.
A `for` loop is easiest to read in its most classing form a counting loop:
it performs some initialization,
then on each iteration it does its main work in the body.
Here, the main work to do is the counting.
So if you transform this to a `while` loop with a body,
it becomes slightly easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. About the variable scope thing: declaring this variable in the for loop means that it will be declared on every iteration, instead of just once. Also, from what I know - coding conventions say that variables should be declared at the beginning of the function. I do understand the scope thing, but since it's a local scope and not global I don't think it's so problematic.

Comment: @John In all modern languages, it's recommended to declare variables in the smallest relevant scope. This has no performance cost. The reasoning is that hiding variables in their relevant scopes avoids mistakes: you cannot mistakenly misuse something that's not visible.

Answer (score 1):

[You said](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/206317/longest-substring-with-2-unique-characters-in-a-given-string-at-linear-time-ja#comment398231_206418):

> Also, from what I know - coding conventions say that variables should be declared at the beginning of the function.

No.  In general, modern coding conventions (e.g. [this one](http://wiki.c2.com/?DeclareVariablesAtFirstUse) or see [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/113262/236539)) say that variables should be declared as late as possible.

Declaring at the beginning was a holdover from the days where people manually allocated memory in machine language/assembly.  Then you had to work out the allocations before running and it made sense to put them all together.  Modernly we let the compiler do that for us.  It has never been the convention in Java.  It was the convention in early C, as the early C compiler *required* declaration at the beginning of the scope.  So you might see that convention if you read older works, like Kernighan and Ritchie.

```
public static String longest2Str(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    if ( (s == null) || (len < 2) ) {
        return null;
    }

    // find first letter in s that isn't equal to the firstUnique 
    int i = 0;
    char firstUnique = s.charAt(i);
    do {
        i++;

        if (i >= len) {
            return null;
        }
    } while (s.charAt(i) == firstUnique);

    char secondUnique = s.charAt(i);
    int subStart = 0;
    int nextGroupStart = i;
    int longestStart = 0;
    int longestEnd = i;
    for (; i < len; i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if ( (c == firstUnique) || (c == secondUnique) ) {
            if (c != s.charAt(i - 1)) {
                nextGroupStart = i;
            }   
        }
        else {
            if ( i - subStart > longestEnd - longestStart ){
                longestStart = subStart;
                longestEnd = i;
            }
            subStart = nextGroupStart;
            nextGroupStart = i;
            firstUnique = s.charAt(subStart);
            secondUnique = c;
        }
    }

    return s.substring(longestStart, longestEnd);
}
```

This moves the declarations just before they are needed.

I changed your first `for` loop to a `do`/`while` for readability, efficiency, and correctness reasons.

I broke out the length check because the return is actually the correct behavior.  If all characters are the same, then there aren't two unique characters.  We can stop and return immediately rather than exiting the loop and checking (what your source did).

When using an empty `for` loop, I would have separated the `) ;` at the end.  The reason is that it makes it easier to see that it's an empty body rather than a function call.  Obviously, it makes no functional difference.  The compiler strips out the whitespace when it tokenizes.